# Why I am getting null value as output when adding 3 columns in the data frame?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

First, I wrote this

```
df_raw_population_pi = spark.sql("SELECT country_code, age_group, cast(regexp_replace(percentage_2019, '[a-z]', '') AS decimal(4,2)) AS percentage_2019, cast(regexp_replace(percentage_2020, '[a-z]', '') AS decimal(4,2)) AS percentage_2020, cast(regexp_replace(percentage_2021, '[a-z]', '') AS decimal(4,2)) AS percentage_2021 FROM raw_population WHERE length(country_code) = 2")
df_raw_population_pi.head(10)
```

The result I'm getting the result with NULL values

```
[Row(country_code='AD', age_group='Y0_14', percentage_2019=Decimal('13.90'), percentage_2020=None, percentage_2021=None),
```

So, I modified my code with

```
("SELECT country_code, age_group, COALESCE(cast(regexp_replace(percentage_2019, '[a-z]', '') AS decimal(4,2)),0) AS percentage_2019, COALESCE(cast(regexp_replace(percentage_2020, '[a-z]', '') AS decimal(4,2)),0) AS percentage_2020, COALESCE(cast(regexp_replace(percentage_2021, '[a-z]', '') AS decimal(4,2)),0) AS percentage_2021 FROM raw_population")
```

in result null value is gone, got replaced with

> 0.00

```
[Row(country_code='AD', age_group='Y0_14', percentage_2019=Decimal('13.90'), percentage_2020=Decimal('0.00'), percentage_2021=Decimal('0.00')),
 Row(country_code='AL', age_group='Y0_14', percentage_2019=Decimal('17.20'), percentage_2020=Decimal('16.80'), percentage_2021=Decimal('16.50')),
 Row(country_code='AM', age_group='Y0_14', percentage_2019=Decimal('20.20'), percentage_2020=Decimal('20.30'), percentage_2021=Decimal('0.00')),
 Row(country_code='AT', age_group='Y0_14', percentage_2019=Decimal('14.40'), percentage_2020=Decimal('14.40'), percentage_2021=Decimal('14.40')),
```

but when I tried to add the three columns i.e. **percentage_2019, percentage_2020, percentage_2021**

```
df_raw_population_pivot = spark.sql("SELECT country_code, age_group, (percentage_2019 + percentage_2020 + percentage_2021) AS sum_percentage_years FROM raw_population WHERE length(country_code) = 2")
df_raw_population_pivot.head(10)
```

I'm getting **NULL** again in the result.

```
[Row(country_code='AD', age_group='Y0_14', sum_percentage_years=None),
 Row(country_code='AL', age_group='Y0_14', sum_percentage_years=50.5),
 Row(country_code='AM', age_group='Y0_14', sum_percentage_years=None),
 Row(country_code='AT', age_group='Y0_14', sum_percentage_years=43.2),
```

i.e., the values of

> percentage_2019 which is 13.0 + percentage_2020 which is 0.00 +
> percentage_2021 which is 0.00 = NULL

I'm totally confused, anyone can help me?

Comment: What does the raw data look like?

Comment: Solved it, there was a silly mistake by my side only

Comment: could you please post your findings as an answer so that other community members will refer it if they face same issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

The Mistake I did is, on the very first step I was reading and importing data from blob storage and created a **data_frame** and **temp view** as below.

```
df_raw_population = spark.read.csv("/mnt/covidreportingpro1/raw/population", sep=r'\t', header=True)
df_raw_population = df_raw_population.withColumn('age_group', regexp_replace(split(df_raw_population['indic_de,geo\\time'], ',')[0], 'PC_', '')).withColumn('country_code', split(df_raw_population['indic_de,geo\\time'], ',')[1])
df_raw_population = df_raw_population.select(col("country_code").alias("country_code"),                                       col("age_group").alias("age_group"),col("2019 ").alias("percentage_2019"),col("2020 ").alias("percentage_2020"),                                 col("2021 ").alias("percentage_2021"))
df_raw_population.createOrReplaceTempView("raw_population")
```

Now I performed cast operation (to change datatype from string to decimal) for **percentage_2019, percentage_2020, percentage_2020** on this `raw_population`.
with below code.

```
df_raw_population_pi = spark.sql("SELECT country_code, age_group, COALESCE(cast(regexp_replace(percentage_2019, '[a-z]', '') AS decimal(4,2)),0) AS percentage_2019, COALESCE(cast(regexp_replace(percentage_2020, '[a-z]', '') AS decimal(4,2)),0) AS percentage_2020, COALESCE(cast(regexp_replace(percentage_2021, '[a-z]', '') AS decimal(4,2)),0) AS percentage_2021 FROM raw_population WHERE length(country_code) = 2")
df_raw_population_pi.createOrReplaceTempView("raw_population_pi")
```

Here, I created a new data frame and temp view i.e. `df_raw_population_pi` and `raw_population_pi`.

The stupidity I did is in next step where I'm adding those percentage columns, instead of importing data from `raw_population_pi` in `FROM` I imported from `raw_population`. Just look below-

```
df_raw_population_pivot = spark.sql("SELECT country_code, age_group, (percentage_2019 + percentage_2020 + percentage_2021) AS sum_percentage_years FROM raw_population WHERE length(country_code) = 2").groupBy("country_code").pivot("age_group").sum("sum_percentage_years").orderBy("country_code")
df_raw_population_pivot.createOrReplaceTempView("raw_population_pivot")
```

instead of this I was supposed to write,

```
df_raw_population_pivot = spark.sql("SELECT country_code, age_group, (percentage_2019 + percentage_2020 + percentage_2021) AS sum_percentage_years FROM raw_population_pi WHERE length(country_code) = 2").groupBy("country_code").pivot("age_group").sum("sum_percentage_years").orderBy("country_code")
df_raw_population_pivot.createOrReplaceTempView("raw_population_pivot")
```

I wasted huge amount of time on this stupid mistake. (Focus on `FROM` on each line above).